# Why can't I solder to this micro USB adapter?

Tags: usb, soldering

I cut the head off a micro USB power supply thinking I could improvise a full micro USB cable. I found only Vcc and gnd wires. So, I decided to tear into the connector itself. Inside the connector was this USB to micro USB adapter. Seems like 5-to-4 wiring with one of the pins on the 5-pin side not connected to anything--how a micro USB to USB should be wired. I tested connectivity with a multimeter, but I can't get any solder to stick on the D+ and D- pins on the 4-pin side. What type of material is this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try scraping it and or scratching it, then hold the solder iron on the material for a while to heat it up and apply solder directly to the solder iron and the material at the same time.

Comment: The scratching / filing / sanding of the surface to remove oxidation is as important as using enough flux in my experience. That applies to the wire as well. By it's black colour the wire appears to be heavily oxidized. Tin the wire first. (I can't tell properly from the photo if the wire is tinned or black.)

Comment: I spent ~20min trying different techniques except for scratching the surface and using flux. Will try those.

Answer (score 2):

Can't really tell from the photo what material it is... but have you tried putting some [flux](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bGckVJeG6b8) on it (and heating it of course)? The surface may be quite oxidized even though it may appear fine.

Comment: Will try some flux. Thx

Answer (score -3):

Probably aluminium. Aluminium forms an oxide layer over time making hard to solder to. Try scraping it as said above, there is special aluminium flux you can buy that will help to remove the oxide layer.

Comment: No.  Aluminum is not used in such applications, precisely because of the oxide.  Aluminum in only used in electrical/electronic applications where the special measures required to make it possible are offset by an advantage, and this is not one of those places.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Nickel then?

Comment: Its best to make a comment on the original post as opposed to an answer if you're not sure or only have a probable answer

Comment: ^^ This is why I hate this site. Make a mistake, everyone is eager to call you out but they aren't willing to provide the answer

Comment: @MikeSeeds: Nickel actually solders fairly easily.

Comment: It's a three year old question that already has **correct** answers.